# Testing a stubbed service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, stub

In a component OnInit I'm fetching some data:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(users => {
        this.users= users.data;
    });
}
```

In my tests, I stub this service:

```
const UserServiceStub =  {
  getUsers(): Observable<any> {
    return of([{name: 'john doe'}, {name: 'jane doe'}]);
  }
};
```

I define a provider:

```
providers: [ { provide: UserService, useValue: UserServiceStub } ],
```

Now I want to test that the call has been made and that data has been set on an element.

```
  it('should be initialized with users', fakeAsync(() => {
    const spy = spyOn(UserServiceStub, 'getUsers').and.callThrough();
  }));
```

It looks like I can call `and.returnValue` but I want the data to come from the stub and I need to set the `Users` property of my component so that I can verify a list in my template is updated.

I couldn't pass a callback to `callThrough` and I didn't find `callthough().apply()` useful.

How do I get my stub execute?

Comment: What is the issue here? Are you calling `ngOnInit()` or `fixture.detectChanges()` after creating the spy?

Comment: @AmitChigadani the issue is I want to do something like expect(component.users).toNotBeNull(); but component.users is undefined even after adding component.ngOnInit()  and fixture.detectChanges()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `spy` object is probably wrong, you should get the instance of an injected service `UserService` and `spy` on its method.

```
let userService: UserService;
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [ { provide: UserService, useValue: UserServiceStub } ],
  });
   userService = TestBed.get(UserService);
});

it('should be initialized with users', fakeAsync(() => {
    const spy = spyOn(userService , 'getUsers').and.callThrough();
}));
```

Comment: So I need to spy on the real service not on the stub? That didn't work anyway. There is nowhere in the test where I can set component.users = stub.getUsers...

Comment: Stub is just to avoid making any `http` calls or to return mock data. You should always spy on the actual service injected

Comment: Thanks I understand. So where do I set my component.users array? In the component it is done onInit by subscribing to the service, but in the test there's nowhere to set the property

Comment: You do not have to set component's property in your spec, then what is the purpose of testing if we do that. It should automatically set from the subscribe block. Just log inside `subscribe` and see if you can see the log once stub return the value.

Comment: Also add your full spec, that should help more

Comment: no luck... my setup is exactly like this https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/testing/components/async.html except the method is in OnInit

Comment: Thanks for the help! My real service returns an array wrapped in data but not my stub :D It's working now